# Entity Framework Core: how to use or condition to connection the Where sentence?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to find the data, which its loginId is in the input array. But EFCore will use AND sentence to connect. This is not my expectation. How do I rewrite this search sentence to make it using OR sentence to connect?

I use this sentence to find the answer:

```
names.ForEach( item=> query = query.Where(x => x.User.LoginId.Contains(item)));
(names is the input array)
```

Comment: See `Union` and `Concat`.

Comment: Remove `ForEach` and just use `query.Where(x => names.Contains(x.User.LoginId))`